# insert/update and also avoiding sql injection

Tags: php, sql, security, sql-injection

I want to check if somethign exist in the database before I update/insert. This is a two question in one but similar.

This is how I do it.

```
$p->main .= '<td><input type="text" name="value"  id="value"  size="12" maxlength="50" />';

    $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT year, month, name table_test WHERE MLOV_year= :Year 
                 AND month= month AND name= :name");

                $bind = array(
                                'year' => $year,
                                'month'   = > $month,
                'name' = > $name
                );


                $statement->tyu_exec_sql_bind($conn,$statement, $bind );

                 if ( false === $statement->fetch()) {
                               // I will run an insert statement here.
                }



    $p->main .= '</td>';
    $p->main .= '</tr>';
```

**Question** 
This is my first time trying it this way and I was wondering if that is right? also if that is security?

Comment: use prepared statemens with PDO

Comment: @perdeu this is what I normally use for years but this code i am write was done by someone else which connect to oracle database and it works similar to mysqli. I am trying to avoid someone trying to use an sql injection.

Comment: Bookmark this => http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1415724 and this => https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10

Comment: What kind of Database library do you use? What object is "$statement" ? Depending on the used library, a bind can range from anything to just inserting variables (Unsafe) to filtering and mapping types (safe).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the database, you might be able to use `MERGE`, which does exactly that, inserting a record if it doesn't exist and updating it if it does, **atomically**.

This is preferrable to any check you do yourself, since that makes it a two step process. In theory, someone else could insert the record between your check and your insert, making your insert fail.

---

Use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection. You did that in your first bit of code, why not in your second?

And a tip, don't call your variable 'delete' when it contains an update statement, that confuses the next person to read this.

Comment: For MySQL see for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-to-table-or-update-if-exists-mysql).

Comment: @SQB. I am trying to prevent sql inject because of the `'".  ."'` from my understand someone can run an sql injection. I want to avoid this before I run the check insert where I am running the insert statement and also when I am running an update. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check that the value exists in database, which means you need to query for it, and then take the decision of update or delete.

You could also set a unique key constraint in a table which would prevent inserting duplicate values.